# Explain why $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-1}}{t!}=1 - \frac{1}{e}$

Tags: expectation, poisson-distribution

Just want to know the step in between calculating this that I forgot about when I took probability theory 5 years ago. We have 
$$E\left(\frac{1}{1+X}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+1}P(X=k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-1}}{(k+1)!} = \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-1}}{t!}$$

This is suppose to equal $1 - \frac{1}{e}$ but I seem to have forgotten the step after this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had assumed you forgot the factorial in the second-to-last passage. Is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wolfi, Here is the missing step in detail:

$$\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-1}}{t!}=e^{-1}\left(\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t!}\right)=e^{-1}\left(\left(\sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t!}\right)-1\right)=e^{-1}(e-1)=1 - \frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 3):

The sum on the right is equal to $e^{-1}(e-1)=1-\frac{1}{e}$ since $e=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t!}$.

Comment: Could you show me a bit more detail, my apologies I seem to have forgot the manipulation trick

Comment: $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t!}=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t!}-1=e-1$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: we have $$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-1}}{t!} = e^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t!} = e^{-1}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t!} - 1= 1 - \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: You're missing parentheses in the second-to-last term, but yes that's it.